# Importing only what you need?

Tags: node.js, webpack, yarnpkg

I was at a meetup recently and one of the talks was about how you can use Webpack to require just the pieces of a package that you need. I believe that it is called tree shaking. I was wondering if there is a way to do this without Webpack? For instance can you specify exactly the pieces of code you need rather than the whole node module.

Any information about this would be great. I am just looking to learn something new.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple pretty simple ways:

In ES6, you can do what is called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Here's an example with arrays:

```
var a, b, rest;
[a, b] = [10, 20];

console.log(a);
// expected output: 10

console.log(b);
// expected output: 20

[a, b, ...rest] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

console.log(rest);
// expected output: [30,40,50]
```

This is destructuring by index, where a = array[0], b=array of index 1 (hyperlink barred bracket format), etc... Notice the `...` operator, called the spread operator in ES6. [Here is a link to that if you are curious about what it does, or how to use it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

You can also do the same with objects, consider:

```
const someRandomObject = {
     a: 1,
     b: 2,
};

const {a} = someRandomObject;
console.log(a) // expected output: 1
```

You are destructing, by name, only the properties you need from the object, so you are not pulling in a bunch of unused stuff. If you are not using ES6, you can do something similar with:

```
const someRandomObject = {
     a: 1,
     b: 2,
};

const a = someRandomObject.b;
console.log(a) // expected output: 2
```

Same thing as above, you are pulling out of someRandomObject the property you want, and nothing else. Note that the above way is pulling the value on the right side, so the name of the variable does not matter. These two ways are functionally equivalent (I believe).

Comment: I think this answer is misleading, and that Sam did not exactly understood the question, even if this answer was accepted. Tree shacking is a way to prevent entire scripts to reach the browser when an user is loading a page. Like, you do `import {debounce} from 'lodash_es'` and then ONLY the debounce function will reach the browser [instead, if you `const debounce = require('lodash')`] you will download the entire lodash library.

Comment: My question does not answer tree shaking, correct. But, the actual question he has is: For instance can you specify exactly the pieces of code you need rather than the whole node module?

Comment: With node modules, you are going to end up with the entire library regardless unless you are transpiling everything and adding tree shaking in the middle.